# display formatting marks for WPF RichtextBox

Tags: wpf, formatting, richtextbox

It seems that my previous question was not clear. So I reforumulate it: I have a richtextbox (WPF, C#) and I want that when a user type a text therein at run time, the formartting marks are dynamically displayed. that is to say, replacing a whitespace with a dot, tabulation with ->, and end-of-paragraph with correspondant marks as MSWord does. Here, what I hope to obtain:

[image]

Comment: you would need to use an IValueConverter to change the text to intercept the value between the control and Model, though this could also be done in the viewModel where the formatted text and the actual text are toggled by a bound property

Comment: being beginner in this field, could you please be more explicit. Further, I want that formatting marks remain unprintable, and keep text wrapping.

Comment: was just creating an example for you

Comment: Many thanks for this example, but when i copied and pasted it as it is, I have the following error: "TextFormatter and VM does not exist in the name space:  clr-namespace: WPF_ScratchPad". Please, how how to overcome this .

Comment: you need to wrap your classes in a namespace i used `namespace WPF_ScratchPad` you can use what ever you want just make sure your `x:Class="WPF_ScratchPad.MainWindow` and `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ScratchPad"` is correct for you

Comment: It is "RaisePropertyChanged" of Prism which causes problem. There is any alternative ?

Comment: just add the Prism.WPF nugget package to your project or write your own BindableBase class you can find the source here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your VM to format in this manor or you can use a IValueConverter

e.g.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_ScratchPad.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ScratchPad"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextFormatter x:Key="TextFormatter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Stored Text">
            <TextBox MaxLines="50" MinLines="5" Text="{Binding Text}" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Converter Formatter">
            <TextBox MaxLines="50" MinLines="5" Text="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource TextFormatter}}" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </GroupBox>

        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowForattnig}">Show Format Marks</CheckBox>
        <GroupBox Header="VM Formatted">
            <TextBox MaxLines="50" MinLines="5" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

View Model

```
public class VM:BindableBase
{
    public TextFormatter Formmatter { get; } = new TextFormatter();
    private string _Text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set
        {
            if(SetProperty(ref _Text, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayText));
            }
        }
    }


    public string DisplayText
    {
        get
        {
            if (ShowForattnig)
                return Formmatter.Convert(Text);
            else
                return Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ShowForattnig)
                Text = Formmatter.ConvertBack(value);
            else
                Text = value;

        }
    }


    private bool _ShowForattnig;

    public bool ShowForattnig
    {
        get { return  _ShowForattnig; }
        set
        {
            if(SetProperty(ref _ShowForattnig, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayText));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**note: as i was doing the value converter anyway i've referenced that but you could just put the code in directly**

Value Converter

```
public class TextFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Replacements { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {Environment.NewLine,$"¶{Environment.NewLine}" },
        {" ","•" }
    };
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => Convert(value?.ToString());

    public string Convert(string value)
    {
        StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder( value);
        foreach (var item in Replacements)
        {
            format = format.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        return format.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => ConvertBack(value?.ToString());

    public string ConvertBack(string value)
    {
        StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder(value);
        foreach (var item in Replacements)
        {
            format = format.Replace(item.Value, item.Key);
        }
        return format.ToString();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: using Prism here for boiler plates**

Comment: Thanks a lot MikeT !! it works now !  However, the formatting marks are printable (i.e. when I copy-paste the typed text from the textbox to MSWord the marks are also pasted).  Can we display formatting marks on another layer with adorner so that they come non-printable ?

Comment: you'll have to override the default copy paste behaviour see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It may be possible to do this with Adorners, i haven't looked into it but i would definitely say you need to improve your grasp of the basics before moving on to the more advance features

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mike !